# Select specific text from json string

Tags: java, json, regex

I have `Json` data returning dates of some events. like this

```
 [{
       "date": "Wed Nov 25 05:56:48 +0000 2016",
       "date": "Wed Nov 24 05:56:48 +0000 2015",
       "date": "Wed Nov 25 05:56:48 +0000 2015"
    }]
```

But I want have only "Wed Nov 25" format(**day and date may change as json data get updated every time**).

 like this

```
Wed Nov 25
Wed Nov 24 
Wed Nov 25
```

Is there a way of doing that in `java`(if possible then with regex)?

regards.

Comment: Your provided Json is invalid. Json should have a key value pair. Can you provide a valid json?

Comment: thanks for your comment @Patrick. It was a demo, but i'll update it.

Comment: I think regex is unnecessary if it is JSON data. You can just use a parsers and a little trappings like `contains`.

Comment: Do you need a String or a util.date of your dates?

Comment: @JanLeeYu Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I need to fetch "Wed Nov 25 or whatever the date" from the above json.

Comment: so you need only last record in json. Will there be only 3 records in json?

Comment: they are not fixed @SangramJadhav

Comment: what do you mean by `"Wed Nov 25 or whatever the date"` @Atula

Comment: the date is changing  so I need to fetch the date in the above format from the json

Comment: can you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the answer to my question, but for the time I have used a trick.
 I have used the `substring` concept like,

```
String timeFeed = gson.toJson(myArrayOfDate);
timeFeed = timeFeed.substring(0,11);
```

This only give me 12 characters which are `Wed Nov 24` format.

**NOTE**: If anyone have answer for my question please share.